# How do I fill the "var" from a LINQ query into the same datatable?

Tags: c#, database, linq, ado.net, datatable

I am fairly new to LINQ and am trying to apply this query on a datatable called "EmpInfo" to sort it.

```
var sortedRows = (from myRow in EmpInfoDS.Tables["EmpInfo"].AsEnumerable()
                 orderby myRow["EmpID"] ascending
                 select myRow).ToArray();
```

This works. The next thing I am trying to do is to copy the results into the SAME datatable.

```
EmpInfoDS.Tables["EmpInfo"].Clear();
EmpInfoDS.Tables["EmpInfo"] = sortedRows.CopyToDataTable();
```

The second line throws the following error:

> "Property or indexer 'System.Data.DataTableCollection.this[string]'
>   cannot be assigned to -- it is read only"

Please some one tell me how to deal with this. And if there is another way please tell me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error says that you can't assign the table using indexers because `Tables` is a **readonly property**. So to solve the problem:

```
EmpInfoDS.Tables.Remove("EmpInfo");
DataTable dt = sortedRows.CopyToDataTable();
dt.TableName = "EmpInfo";
EmpInfoDS.Tables.Add(dt);
```

Comment: I don't think the first line's in C#. o_O

Comment: @Fuex: it should be `.Remove()`, LOL

Comment: Sincerly I don't know, but I think that it doesn't decrease the performance so much. It depends on the Remove() method and how it works.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is how it can be done: (you might prefer a different [`LoadOption`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.loadoption.aspx))

```
EmpInfoDS.Tables["EmpInfo"].Clear();
sortedRows.CopyToDataTable(EmpInfoDS.Tables["EmpInfo"], LoadOption.OverwriteChanges);
```

This should also work:

```
EmpInfoDS.Tables["EmpInfo"].Clear();
foreach (var row in sortedRows)
    EmpInfoDS.Tables["EmpInfo"].Rows.Add(row);
```

Comment: The first one gives the following error "The source contains a detached DataRow that cannot be copied to the DataTable. "
 I have already tried the second one but that just shows an empty a datatable with empty ROWS.

Answer (score 0):

With LINQ, you have to watch out for deferred execution.  Basically, queries are not executed until the data from the query is consumed.  If you want a query to execute immediately, use the `ToList()` method.

```
var sortedRows = EmpInfoDS.EmpInfo.OrderBy(e => e.EmpID).ToList();
```

Next, the code is straight forward:

```
var employees = EmpInfoDS.EmpInfo;
employees.Clear();
foreach (var sortedRow in sortedRows)
    employees.Add(sortedRow);
EmpInfoDS.SaveChanges();
```

Comment: EmpInfo is created by filling the dataset from a database with a dataadapter. What you are suggesting is for a table that has been created manually. I tried your code and it didn't work. Thanks